# Brew Cassandra Installation

Tags: cassandra, homebrew

I am on Mac OS High Sierra.

I did the following

```
brew install cassandra
brew services start cassandra 
cqlsh localhost


~ > cqlsh localhost
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'::1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('::1', 9042, 0, 0)]. Last error: Connection refused"), '127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? is there any step in between?

Comment: I installed cassandra with brew in mac os as well, sometimes `services` command might not bring it up. Normally, I ran `cassandra -f` in another terminal and checked if it's up properly or not.

Comment: You are right. I did `brew services stop cassandra` and then did `cassandra -r` and now i was able to cqlsh successfully.

Comment: I am glad it helps

Comment: but how do you ensure that cassandra autostarts when mac starts?

Comment: understand your concern, what I did is to configure auto-start and number of retry for this service. It's not 100% sure, but it's good enough for me as I am doing development in macos only. In production deployment, we make use of systemd in linux redhat.

Comment: It's 2020.6.24, and I ran across this issue - brew services start cassandra fails to actually start cassandra. I used the following steps to resolve the issue:                      1. brew services stop cassandra
2. brew unlink cassandra && brew link cassandra
3. brew services start cassandra
4. cqlsh    ( cassandra -f ( or -r ) will also run cassandra.) ( always verify with cqlsh ) I've never had an issue with homebrew services until now.

Comment: It's 2021.3.7 and I'm having the same issue. Like everyone else, `cassandra -f` works, but I'd like to understsand why `brew services start cassandra` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

For the future viewer, adding to the comment by @Apolozeus you might also want to check if Cassandra was linked after it was installed by brew.

`> brew link cassandra`

This will create symlinks, after this you can invoke cassandra.

`> cassandra`

`> cqlsh`